# Google App Engine Analog without subscription fee

Tags: java, cloud-hosting

After the introduction of recurrent fee GAE has lost any sense for me. Is there any analogues without subscription fee?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific; what functionality are you looking for?

That said, GAE appears to have a free version; what functionality are you using that's in the billable packages?

https://cloud.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Unlimited bandwidth and storage without subscription fee. Pay only for what use, no minimum $9 monthly.